# Custom buttons and states in iOS

Tags: ios, image, uibutton, state

This is a question for people that have already submitted an app to Apple Store: is it required, for a custom `UIButton` you're setting an image or a background, to set one for each button state? Sometimes I only set a button image for the normal state, and then the system puts a default highlight when the button is tapped, but I've seen that in Xcode's console sometimes some messages appear saying that some button's states are not set...

Thanks!

**EDIT.** Messages in console are similar to this:

```
button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateDisabled. state = 4 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.
```

Comment: Update your question with the actual message you are seeing.

Comment: You are not required to provide images for every button state. You're not even required to provide an image for one state.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook You're right, but in case you are providing an image for the button... is it not required to provide it for all states?

Comment: No, it's not required.

Comment: @rmaddy `button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateDisabled. state = 4 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.`

Answer (score 1):

No - it is merely optional to call `setImage:forState` on your UIButton. Do this only as you see fit.